# Change button actions sequence swift

Tags: macos, swift, xcode6, nsbutton

I have a button connected both to `@IBAction` in ViewController and another ViewController (with another class name). When I press the button, a new ViewController opens, but code in @IBAction is never executed. Is there any way to set the sequence if button actions (first must be @IBAction, and then transition to another ViewController) ?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you made a segue to the second viewController from the button AND made an IBAction in the first viewController?

Comment: @Tuslareb, yes, you understood me right

Comment: @CodingSource, there's only `@IBAction func firstFunc(sender: NSButton) { println("Working") }` and a segue between button and another view controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it isn't working, but what you can do is make a manual segue from the first viewController to the second viewController, instead from the button the second viewController.

Then, in IBAction, programmatically perform this manual segue:

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("manualSegue", sender: self)
```

To make a manual segue, control drag from the viewController icon to the second viewController. Give this segue an unique identifier and use it in the `performSegueWithIdentifier` method.